# What is the best way to make string variables accessible entire project

Tags: c#, asp.net

My project is written in ASP.NET C#, I have some const strings like:

```
Constant string str1 = "VAL1";
Constant string str2 = "VAL2";
```

I want to use these strings globally.
What is the best way?

Comment: Define "all projects". Simply stick them in a class an assembly, and reference that assembly with all projects?

Comment: thanks, I improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well depends what is the usage of those strings, if you are using them for configuration, or similar reasons, i suggest to put them in web.config.
You can create a specific section of put it in appSettings for example:

```
<add key="HelpdeskContact" value="Please contact helpdesk on 0123456" />
```

Comment: the strings are variable for calculation and doing some processes

Answer (score 2):

I think that creating a dedicated **Class Library** with a class that holds the constants and then add that project as a reference (or even create a **NuGet** package from that project and use that instead) to all projects that require those constants is the best way to go.

The class could look something like the following:

```
public static class MyConstants
{
    public const string str1 = "VAL1";
    public const string str2 = "VAL2";
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: static classes cannot be instantiated. Also, static classes are sealed. So no need to add the ctor

Comment: Yea, you're right, two ideas got mixed while I was writing the answer. Fixed.